# Função que retorna ponteiro dá crash quando tenta retornar ponteiro ao programa principal

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, funções

Tenho esta função que recupera um registro de um arquivo binário já preenchido com registros - tais registros estão estruturados como *node* - e o retorna ao programa.
Só que no retorno de "i" para a variável do programa principal "teste", sendo as duas to tipo estruturado *node*, o programa deixa de responder.

Estou disposto a mudar qualquer parâmetro da função, mas preciso que ela leia um *node* do arquivo binário e retorne este *node* para o programa principal.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node 
{
    void ** pointers;
    int * keys;
    struct node * parent;
    bool is_leaf;
    int num_keys;
    struct node * next; 
} node; 

    node* carrega_node (char *nome){   
        FILE * fp;  
        node * i;  
        fp = fopen (nome, "rb");  
        fread (&i, sizeof(node), 1, fp);  
        fclose (fp);  
        return i;  
    };  

    int main()  
    node * teste  

    teste = carrega_node ("candidatos.idx");
    return 0;
```

Comment: Como está a `struct node`? O *layout* dela encaixa perfeitamente no que vem do arquivo? No arquivo você provavelmente tem um texto. Não pode simplesmente jogar este texto para a `struct`. Até pode, mas provavelmente não é o que você quer fazer. Além disto você não alocou memória para `i`.

Comment: Como eu suspeitei você tem problemas bem mais sérios para carregar a informação do arquivo para a memória. Na verdade nem imagino como está o arquivo. Pode colocar um trecho dele?

Comment: estrutura do node adicionada, mas veja que não muito é relevante para gente. Você diz que no arquivo provavelmente eu tenho texto, o que não é verdade. Pense em node como um tipo estruturado qualquer. O arquivo aqui é um arquivo binário que guarda *nodes*. O objetivo é recuperar um node e retorná-lo ao programa principal.

Comment: Você pode não ter um texto mas tem algo que não vai encaixar na estrutura. Como não sei o que tem, não dá para ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Houve alguma confusão com a sintaxe, isso não faz o que parece que faz. Observe:

```
node* i; // Cria uma variável local do tipo node*. Esse ponteiro aponta para nada

fread(&i, sizeof(node), 1, fp); // Escreve sizeof(node) na variável i. Observe que
                                // i é um ponteiro que tem apenas 4 ou 8 bytes. Mas
                                // sizeof(node) pode ser bem maior que isso. Você
                                // está tentando ler um nodo ou um ponteiro para um nodo?
```

Aqui tem dois problemas. O primeiro é que lê um nodo inteiro do arquivo e escreve por cima do próprio ponteiro para um nodo. E o segundo problema é que se quer ler um nodo, precisa primeiro alocar memória suficiente para armazenar esse nodo. Correção:

```
node* i = malloc(sizeof(node)); // Aloca memória que caiba um nodo.

fread(i, sizeof(node), 1, fp);  // Lê um nodo e coloca nessa memória.
//    ^ note que estou passando o ponteiro para a memória alocada,
//      não um ponteiro para o ponteiro.
```

Lembre-se que depois de acabar de usar o nodo, deve liberar a memória que foi alocada usando `free(i)`.

---

Mas por que o **crash** ocorreu? Assuma que um ponteiro tem 4 bytes e que um nodo tem 16 bytes.

```
sizeof(node)   // 16
sizeof(node*)  // 4
```

No momento que `fread(&i, sizeof(node), 1, fp);` for executado, o programa escreverá 16 bytes de dados em uma variável em que cabem 4 bytes. Os 12 bytes extras serão cegamente escritos na memória corrompendo qualquer dado que antes estava ali. Curiosamente a informação que estava ali antes era o endereço de retorno da função. Logo, no momento que executar o `return`, a execução pulará para outra parte não relacionada do programa, fora do main. E isso causará um **crash**.

---

### Mas você tem um problema ainda mais grave:

Está salvando e lendo sua estrutura de um arquivo. Mas essa estrutura contém ponteiros. Não há problema algum em salvar ponteiros em um arquivo. Mas eles passam a não ter nenhum significado útil. Pois quando você carrega eles, em outra execução do programa, eles estarão apontando para uma memória que não tem nada. O layout de memória de um processo muda completamente quando reexecuta. E salvar o ponteiro para dados não é similar a salvar os próprios dados.

Não é diretamente possível salvar uma lista lincada em um arquivo. Precisa primeiro transformar em um array linear ou algo que não dependa do comportamento de ponteiros para funcionar.